# How to open a specific version of the Python shell through the Python launcher?

Tags: python, anaconda, virtualenv, launcher, pythonpath

I would like to be able to open a prompt and install packages from `cmd` for the all the versions of Python I have installed on my machine (Windows 10).

#### Things that worked well

I have five different `python.exe` at the following locations:

```
C:\Python27
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32
C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3
C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\python27
C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\python36
```

I can open a specific version of the Anaconda prompt by entering:

```
$ activate python27
(python27) $ python
Python 2.7.14 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Oct 15 2017, 03:34:40) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

I can also install packages in a specific environment through the `conda` package manager:

```
$ conda install -n python27 <package_name>
```

The commands above also work if I replace `python27` by `python36`.

I am also able to open a Python 2 console using the launcher:

```
$ py -2
Python 2.7.14 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Oct 15 2017, 03:34:40) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

and to install a package for Python 2 through the `pip` package installer:

```
$ py -2 -m pip install <package_name>
```

So far, so good.

#### Things that didn't work

My problem is that when I change the option `-2`  to `-3`, the launcher runs the `python.exe` located at `C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3`:

```
$ py -3
Python 3.6.3 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Nov  8 2017, 15:10:56) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

rather than the one located at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32`, which is what I was expecting:

```
$ "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\python"
Python 3.6.4 (v3.6.4:d48eceb, Dec 19 2017, 06:04:45) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

I've tried to setup the `Path` environment variable like this, to no avail:

```
C:\windows
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Scripts
C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3
C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\Scripts
```

#### My question

How can I get the expected behaviour, i.e. how can I make the launcher open a Python 3 console instead of an Anaconda 3 prompt?